# Xerces replacing newline in text element

Tags: c++, xerces

I have a program that reads an xml file (the FileZilla settings file), adds a user, and then writes the file again using Xerces.

The problem is that by default the Initial Welcome Message element text contains CR+LF in this format `&#x0D;&#x0A;` and Xerces manages to somehow translate this to an actual CR+LF so the data in the file goes from this

```
<Item name="Initial Welcome Message" type="string">%v&#x0D;&#x0A;written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)&#x0D;&#x0A;Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/</Item>
```

to this

```
<Item name="Initial Welcome Message" type="string">%v
written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/</Item>
```

which shows up incorrectly in the settings of FileZilla and I assume in any calls to the server.

I'm not modifying this part of the file myself, it's simply parsed and then serialized by Xerces using this code:

```
XercesDOMParser parser;

parser.parse(m_settingsPath.c_str());

DOMDocument* doc = parser.getDocument();

// New user added here

DOMImplementation *impl          = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(L"LS");
DOMLSSerializer   *theSerializer = ((DOMImplementationLS*)impl)->createLSSerializer();

DOMConfiguration* serializerConfig=theSerializer->getDomConfig();

if (serializerConfig->canSetParameter(XMLUni::fgDOMWRTFormatPrettyPrint, true))
    serializerConfig->setParameter(XMLUni::fgDOMWRTFormatPrettyPrint, true);

return theSerializer->writeToURI(doc, L"C:\\work\\temp\\test.xml");
```

I assume this can be fixed by modifying some setting in either the parser or the serializer (I don't know where the problem originates) but I have no idea what that setting would be.

Comment: I have pretty bad memories of Xerces from a few years ago. My advice, if you have the possibility to do so, run away from this horror as fast as you can. TinyXML-2 is a possible (much simpler) replacement to consider.

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more, but apart from this little snag it actually does what I want it to do... at least for now...